# iOS NSNumber Invalid operands to binary expression (NSNumber *" and 'double')

Tags: ios, expression, nsnumber, operands

I have the following line of code

```
NSNumber *myValue = loadTempValue*0.420;
```

where I am trying to set the value of `*myValue` to the value of `loadTempValue*0.420`,

However, I get the **error**

`Invalid operands to binary expression ('NSNumber *" and 'double')`

Can someone advise how to set this out?

Comment: The better question is why you think it is OK to assign a `double` value to an object pointer?

Comment: @rmaddy Please can you explain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that `loadTempValue` is also an `NSNumber`. In that case you want:

```
NSNumber *myValue = @([loadTempValue doubleValue] * 0.420);
```

Why are you using `NSNumber` objects for these values?

If `loadTempValue` was a `double` you could just do:

```
double myValue = loadTempValue * 0.42;
```

Comment: Thanks. loadTempValue is set by NSNumber *loadTempValue = [defaults objectForKey:@"tempValue"];. I assume from your comments this is wrong? If so, what way should I be doing it?

Comment: You could do: `double loadTempValue = [defaults doubleForKey:@"tempValue"];`. Assuming `defaults` is `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: OK. Yes it is NSUserDefaults. So is this the better (right) way of doing this? And may I ask the reasoning? Simply as if I understand the reasoning more fully, I am more likely to do it right in future and for me to remember it!

Comment: NSNumber has its place. Use the right tool for the right job. If you are doing math it is easier to use simple types such as `double`. If you need to store those values in an array or dictionary, wrap the values in `NSNumber`.

Comment: Thanks! So if I understand you correctly, work with simple types under normal circumstances but just wrap them in NSNumber when storing. Thanks again.

Comment: to save this value back to NSUserDefaults, having used the double method above, what do I need to wrap this statement in to get it to an NSNumber? [defaults setObject:myValue forKey:@"myValue"]; As this statement now gives me the error "sending 'double' to parameter of incompatible type 'id'

Comment: Look at the docs for `NSUserDefaults`. There is a method for passing in a `double` value.

Comment: Thank you. Found it and sorted. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`NSNumber *myValue = @([loadTempValue doubleValue] * 0.420);`

or

`NSNumber *myValue = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:([loadTempValue doubleValue] * 0.420)];`

Comment: what is `loadTempValue` ?

Answer (score 0):

`loadTempValue` is an `NSNumber *` and `0.420` is a `float`. You're trying to multiply an object by a float which the compiler does not understand.

What you want to do it get the float value from `loadTempValue` and then multiply that by `0.420`. You do that this way:

```
[loadTempValue floatValue] * 0.420;
```

From there, it seems like you want to put that value back into an `NSNumber *` object, you do that like this:

```
@([loadTempValue floatValue] * 0.420);
```

The `@( ... )` syntax was recently introduced to Objective-C. It's called object literal notation for numbers. It is a shorthand way of writing `[NSNumber numberWithFloat: ...]`

Finally, you will want to assign the result to a variable called `myValue`; you can accomplish that like this:

```
NSNumber *myValue = @([loadTempValue floatValue] * 0.420);
```